# Error while importing OSM to PostgreSQL

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to import OSM to PostgreSQL using the osm2pgsql tool.

```
osm2pgsql -cGs -d osm -U postgres -W postgres -H localhost -S /usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style /Users/asmaa/SIG/Projet_SIG/campus.osm
```

I am getting this output with an error:

```
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=800MB, maxblocks=102400*8192, allocation method=11
Mid: pgsql, scale=100 cache=800
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_nodes" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_ways" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_rels" does not exist, skipping

***Reading in file: postgres
error while opening file postgres***
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the -W argument in your prompt. This argument does not take any input, but forces a prompt for the postgres user's password. So to solve your problem remove postgres after the -W argument.

```
osm2pgsql -cGsW -d osm -U postgres -H localhost -S /usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style /Users/asmaa/SIG/Projet_SIG/campus.osm
```